# Debezium: How long does the initial snapshot take?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I'm planning to use Debezium MYSQL Kafka Connector to capture CDC data.
But for taking the `initial` snapshot, as per the documentation it:

```
Grabs a global read lock that blocks writes by other database clients.
```

How long does this take? We do not have a dedicated replica from where we can read and wanted more clarity on how the locking will behave.

It's a medium sized db - tens of tables and 10-100k rows per table.

Comment: By my experience it take couple of minutes.